# How can I connect multiple eCharts charts under a React Frame?

Tags: reactjs, teechart

How can I express the events(such as datazoom, click, etc) of eCharts in a App.js file or a react module? I wish that when I zoom a line chart, a pie chart would change. The two charts shall share the same dataset.

I tried to use echarts.connect, and that didn't work(Of course). And I tried to capture the event, and I failed too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.